# Angular - View bind to array is not updated

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In the code snippet below, `push` function is used to push only the checked row from an array to another. The `push` is performed successfully but the view is not updated.

```
onNextclick() {

    this.disable1 = false;
      this.selectedIndex += 1;
      this.disable = true;
      const filteredItems = this.dataSource.filter(p => p.isChecked);
      this.datasource2.push(...filteredItems);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change detector sees only that dataSource2 refers to same array (even if its elements were changed).

Try this:

```
  this.datasource2 = [...filteredItems]
```